# Interpolation inside a matrix. Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix looks like:

```
    0  0  0  0  0
    1  0  0  0  0
    0  2  0  0  0
    0  0  2  0  0
    0  0  0  1  0
    1  0  0  0  1
    0  4  0  0  0
    0  0  3  0  0
    6  0  0  4  0
    0  3  0  0  2
    0  0  5  0  0
```

It is 11x5 matrix. 
I want to interpolate between the values vertically for each column.

Any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: I know what matricies and interpolation are; I'm not sure what you mean by "interpolate between the values vertically for each column".  Are the values between columns 1 and 2 (0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 0.5, 2.0,....) etc?  Feels like two simple selectors and averaging will do the trick.

Comment: yes i read about it, but i don't know how to do it correctly. It gives wrong values everytime.

Comment: @user3049408 can you provide a hand worked example output?

Comment: I need to do the interpolation for each column so i can fill the gap between the values > 0.
For example: at the first column:
there are 3 values > 0: 1 ,1 ,6
I want to interpolate between those three values for column number one. and so on for the rest of the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
M =[0  0  0  0  0
    1  0  0  0  0
    0  2  0  0  0
    0  0  2  0  0
    0  0  0  1  0
    1  0  0  0  1
    0  4  0  0  0
    0  0  3  0  0
    6  0  0  4  0
    0  3  0  0  2
    0  0  5  0  0];

xi = 1:size(M,1)
for colIdx = 1:size(M,2)
    col = M(:,colIdx);
    x = xi(~~col);  %// Note that ~~col is a logical vector of elements that are not equal to zero. i.e. it's the same as col ~= 0
    y = col(~~col);
    M(:,colIdx) = interp1(x,y,xi);
end
```

then if you want the outer points to be `0` add this line after the loop:

```
M(isnan(M)) = 0;
```

Comment: I tried it. it gives this error:  x = xi(idx);
 
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: @user3049408 try it now. I'd left off a `~` since I'm looking for numbers that aren't zero

Comment: You are awesome.
I don't know how you can do this but it works fine.

Thanks so much

Comment: Column by column (i.e. loop), you need to extract the non-zero elements (`y=col(~~col)`) and find the appropriate x values whicvh is just the row number. `xi` is a list of row numbers so the rows of the now zero elements of a column (`col`) are just `x = xi(~~col)`. Then you just tell it to interpolate for every possible row, i.e. `xi`